# Unable to connect to H2 from a Tomcat Java servlet

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets, h2

I'm having a strange problem with H2 database connection from a Java servlet (running on Tomcat).

The scenario is as following:
First, I run the servlet on the Tomcat 7.0, everything is fine. I can access the static webpage on the localhost. Then, when I try to execute a communication with servlet via HTML form, everything breaks, and I get an exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.h2.Driver
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1718)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1569)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
....
```

and so on.

The thing is, I have the h2 jar file in the classpath (using Eclipse: right click on project -> Properties -> Libraries tab -> Add (External) JARs...). What I really can't understand is that if I run the same code from a non-servlet class (as Java Application), everything works fine and I can connect to the database.

The code I'm using to connect is:

```
try {
    Class.forName("org.h2.Driver").newInstance();//it breaks here
}
catch(Exception Ex) {
    Ex.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
}
catch(Exception Ex){
    Ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

I'm using the exact same connection URL, username and password as for the H2 console, to which I can connect without any problems.

Thanks!

Comment: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.h2.Driver` clearly indicates that you do **not** have the driver on the classpath of your web application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure the library is in the classpath, maybe those settings in Eclipse don't have the effect you expect.

You can manually include the library on WEB-INF/lib. Alternatively you could include the H2 jar in the Tomcat common lib folder.

Comment: Thanks, adding the library to the WEB-INF/lib directory did it!

Answer (score 2):

Either put H2 driver jar in Tomcat's classpath or add the maven dependencies tomcat-jdbc (and probably tomcat-juli) to the pom.xml.

Here is my theory. You have the H2 driver in webapp class loader level (under web-inf\lib) but it's not not accessible by the Tomcat's catalina classes (in server classpath). If you don't have the tomcat-jdbc in the local webapp, then the task of connection pool creation is delegated to the system/server classloader which clearly cannot access the local webapp classloader.